# ISO-8859-1 encoded string to UTF-8 string

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to fetch some meta-data off of some websites. However, a lot of websites has their meta data content saved with ISO-8857-1 encoding, so I get strings like:

```
Alt sammen under &#233;t tag.  Kontakt os i dag p&#229;
```

Being somewhat of an encoding beginner, I'm at a complete loss as to how to get the regular UTF-8 encoded string. I'ved tried with a procedure like this:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
```

which just gives me an even more obscure string. Can someone point me in the right direction? Even stack overflow converts the iso-8859-1 charcters to the correct ones, when I write them inside the quote blocks.

Comment: Note that a numeric character entity reference identifies a Unicode codepoint, as do all the characters in an HTML document after decoding with the document's character encoding. (If you are looking at the content from the perspective of a .NET String, then its encoding is UTF-16. But that's not relevant until you try to index a string in arbitrary places or to determine the "length" of a string.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for
`"Alt sammen under ét tag. Kontakt os i dag på"` as output? 
In that case you might be confusing character encoding with html encoding, which is yet another layer of encoding on top of the page character encoding.

If this is the case, use [system.web.httputility.htmldecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the string as "human-readable".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew I was missing the point at some level. This works.